# Is there something that avoids some characters (1, f, x, and b, specifically) to be validated from an input?

Tags: reactjs, react-tsx

I have a field to validate repeated questions. I must convert special characters into normal letters using a method, and then I use a method to skip spaces and other characters to validate if the new text is equal to the existing questions. In my local everything is working fine, but in a Production instance, it skips characters 1, f, x and b. My project in Production is mounted in Linux.

My two methods are:

```
    replaceSpecialCharacters(output){  
            return output = output.replace(/á|é|í|ó|ú|ñ|ä|ë|ï|ö|ü|à|è|ì|ò|ù/ig,function (str,offset,s) {  
                var str = str=="á"?"a":str=="é"?"e":str=="í"?"i":str=="ó"?"o":str=="ú"?"u":str=="ñ"?"n":str;  
                    str = str=="Á"?"A":str=="É"?"E":str=="Í"?"I":str=="Ó"?"O":str=="Ú"?"U":str=="Ñ"?"N":str;  
                    str = str=="à"?"a":str=="è"?"e":str=="ì"?"i":str=="ò"?"o":str=="ù"?"u":str;  
                    str = str=="À"?"A":str=="È"?"E":str=="Ì"?"I":str=="Ò"?"O":str=="Ù"?"U":str;  
                    str = str=="ä"?"a":str=="ë"?"e":str=="ï"?"i":str=="ö"?"o":str=="ü"?"u":str;  
                    str = str=="Ä"?"A":str=="Ë"?"E":str=="Ï"?"I":str=="Ö"?"O":str=="Ü"?"U":str;  
                return (str);  
            });  
        }
```

```
    validateRepeatedQuestion(question): void {    
            var questionToCheck = this.replaceSpecialCharacters(question).replace(/[(\s)+(\¿)+(\?)+(\¡)+(\!)+(\")+(\')+]/g, "");  
            this.setState({isRepeated: false});    
            for (let i = 0; i < this.props.allQuestions.length; i++) {    
                var questionFromArray = this.replaceSpecialCharacters(this.props.allQuestions[i].text).replace(/[(\s)+(\¿)+(\?)+(\¡)+(\!)+(\")+(\')+]/g, "");    
                if(this.props.allQuestions[i].position != this.props.question.position){   
                    if(questionFromArray.toLocaleLowerCase() == questionToCheck.toLocaleLowerCase()){    
                        this.setState({isRepeated: true});    
                    }   
                }  
            }  
        }
```

If I have a question like "How old are you?" and I try to add a question like "How old are you?1111" I expect the validation to take the new question as different, but the actual output says that the question is repeated, even if I'm adding numbers 1. It must be different.

Comment: That replace special characters function is way more complicated than it needs to be. switch or an object would make that cleaner.

Comment: Would you consider showing this code as a Code Sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/), or someplace else with more context? `validateRepeatedQuestion` knows about a bunch of things (all of the `this.props`) that we don't.